# Vulgate Latin: usque ad pecus

Tags: vulgata

St Jerome has in Gen 7:23, “ab homine usque ad pecus” but pecus is nominative (or perhaps genitive if the word is pecu) and not accusative. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complete verse is

> Et delevit omnem substantiam quae erat super terram, ab homine usque ad pecus, tam reptile quam volucres caeli: et deleta sunt de terra. Remansit autem solus Noe, et qui cum eo erant in arca.

There are two main words with nominative form *pecus*:

1. [pĕcus, pecŏris, neuter](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpecus1)
2. [pĕcus, pecŭdis, generally feminine](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpecus2)

with related meaning. The latter is for an individual member of a herd, the former means *herd* or, generically, *cattle*.

The KJV translation is

> And every living substance was destroyed which was upon the face of the ground, both man, and cattle, and the creeping things, and the fowl of the heaven; and they were destroyed from the earth: and Noah only remained alive, and they that were with him in the ark.

The Lewis and Short entry for pĕcus, pecŏris states

> In late and eccl. lat. the distinction between pecus, f., and pecus, n., nearly disappears, and the latter is found in all senses of the words; cf. Vulg. Lev. 20, 15; id. 2 Par. 14, 15; id. Isa. 66, 3.

So the neuter form is what's meant here and the accusative is the same as the nominative in all neuter nouns.

Answer (score 8):

pecus is actually a neuter noun, so its nominative and accusative singular look the same! (And ad takes an accusative.)

Full morphology of this word [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pecus#:%7E:text=(derogatory)%20A%20mindless%20group%20of,of%20a%20flock%20or%20herd.).

Comment: I’m so embarrassed. I was looking at that very page and managed to look right past the gender and accusative forms.

Comment: @D.A.Hosek Nōn pudeat lābī! You've come to the right web site. I've asked several questions here that were "even below my level" and gotten good answers.